# multiplying many columns with just one column

Tags: excel

I have excel sheet that looks something like this..

```
 A   B  C  ...K.....P  Q R S T

 5   2  7  ...3
```

Say, 5, 2, 7...is the row 1.

I want P1=A1*K1 (I can do that by typing =A1*K1 in P1 - no problem so far).
Then I want Q1=B1*K1,  R1=C1*K1 and so on. Only one of the two items is changing (K1 remains constant). If I drag the cell P1(after typing = A1*K1), it increments both the operands of multiply, so Q1 becomes (B1*L1), R1 becomes C1*M1. I want the first operand to increment normally, but second one should remain K1.

Once this is done, I need to be able to drag the row 1, so that similar thing happens for all the rows.

How can I do that ? Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$`s. Write `P1=A1*$K1`. This ensures that when you are dragging the formula over other columns, the column identifier 'K' will remain the same. You can use `$k$1` if you want to keep `1` the same as well, across many rows.

Comment: No problems man. I assume you can now mark the question as closed by choosing the answer and thus making it go off the front page. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)